# Can I use docker engine with the latest pycharm 2016.3.2 on windows 10 pro

Tags: python, docker, windows-10, pycharm, hyper-v

The [new Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/#/docker-for-windows) runs as a native Windows application and uses Hyper-V to virtualize the Docker Engine. In the pycharm docker plugin I can only use a docker machine to configure docker in Pycharm. But I need to configure a docker engine here.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

see https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/12/using-docker-in-pycharm/#comment-296772

> Since I had a failry hard time getting the remote interpreter running,
>   here is the short version for those using 64bit Windows 10 Pro,
>   Enterprise and Education (1511 November update, Build 10586 or later)
>   as specified here:
>   https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/#/docker-for-windows
>   And in the future hopefully all recent Windows 10 versions.
>
> There is no need to fiddle around with the docker-machine. When Docker
>   is up and running:
>   1. Make sure you share the C drive between Docker and your local machine
>   2. When specifying the remote interpreter set tcp://localhost:2375 as API URL. That’s it.
>
> Regards, Markus

In later versions of Docker for Windows, you have to manually enable listening on port 2375:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing.